# Get all words before the last word in PHP

Tags: php

I want to put the last word of a string to the beginning of a new string.

I have only a solution, if the string contains not more than 2 words. How to change my code to get the desired result, if the string contains could contain 2 or more words. It should work for 2 words like now and for more than 2 words.

```
$string = 'second first';

function space_check($string){
    if (preg_match('/\s/',$string)) 
            return true;    
    }
    if (space_check($string) == true )  {
        $arr = explode(' ',trim($string));
        $new_string = mb_substr($string,  mb_strlen($arr[0])+1);            
        $new_string.=  ' ' . $arr[0];
    }

    echo $new_string; // result: first second

    $string2 = 'second third first';
    echo $new_string; // desired result: first second third (now 'third first second')
```

I need also a solution for the `+1` in `mb_strlen($arr[0])+1`part, because I want if the string contains for example three words, it has to be +2 and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// initial string
$string2 = 'second third first';

// separate words on space
$arr = explode(' ', $string2);

// get last word and remove it from the array
$last = array_pop($arr);

// now push it in front
array_unshift($arr, $last);

// and build the new string
$new_string = implode(' ', $arr);
```

Here is the [working example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/221f2df86dd3aefeae4a18f968e2af0a97be96ee) and [relevant](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php) [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php).

Answer (score 2):

An even simpler method than exploding would be to find the position of the last space and substring it.

```
$str = 'second third first';
$firstword = substr($str, strrpos($str, " ")+1);
$rest = substr($str, 0, strrpos($str, " "));
echo $firstword . " " . $rest;
```

The first substr prints from last space til end, the next substr prints from start to last space.

https://3v4l.org/2BUTc

EDIT; forgot the +1 at the first substr. My previous code printed `space first.....`

Answer (score 1):

You could do this very simple by using `explode` and `array_pop`.

```
$string = 'This is your string';
$words = explode(' ', $string);

$last_word = array_pop($words);
```

After `array_pop` is used, `$words` will contain all the words except for the last one. Now you have the string, and you could easily concatenate the `$last_word` before the desired string.

Comment: I like this solution! :)

Comment: Thank you, but how to put the  `$last_word` in your solution in a new string, where the last word of  `$string`  should be at the beginning?